# tokenized output into an array from string

Tags: java

i am working on netbeans...i need to read a file and tokenize then and store it in an array for my future operations....i have attached the code where the line5 contains the tokens...while converting into array iam getting error as

Exception :

```
" Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1000
at preprocess.mainpage.jButton2ActionPerformed(mainpage.java:224)
at preprocess.mainpage.access$100(mainpage.java:18)
at preprocess.mainpage$2.actionPerformed(mainpage.java:62)"
```

Code:

```
int counter=-1;
           int n=0;
           String[] arr = new String[1000];
try
{

    BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/Users/sky/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Preprocess/src/preprocess/cdr1.txt"));
                    String line;
                    while ((line = b.readLine()) != null)
                    {
                       counter+=1;
                       StringTokenizer st2 = new StringTokenizer(line, " ");
                       String line5 = (String) st2.nextElement();
                       arr[n] = line5;
                       n++;
                    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
}
```

Comment: where have you declare array variable arr. please provide full code.

Comment: More over exception will clearly tell you on which line your ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException occured.

Comment: better use ArrayList if you don't know the size beforehand

Comment: the exception occured in the line "arr[n]=line5"; and i need to use array...i need indexing..

Comment: are you sure you are getting error in "arr[n] = line5" ? your code seems to be correct only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html)  because may be your array size is less. So better use `ArrayList` like following:

```
int counter=-1;
int n=0;
//String[] arr = new String[1000];
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(); // Create ArrayList
try{    
    BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/Users/sky/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Preprocess/src/preprocess/cdr1.txt"));
    String line;
    while ((line = b.readLine()) != null) {
         counter+=1;
         StringTokenizer st2 = new StringTokenizer(line, " ");
         String line5 = (String) st2.nextElement();
         //arr[n] = line5;
         //n++;
         list.add(line5); // Add you string into list
   }
 String[] aa = list.toArray(new String[0]); // convert list into String of array if you need it
}
catch (Exception e){
}
```